# SQLite execute VACUUM

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have updated NuGet packages from 'sqlite-net-pcl' for SQLite, after this I receive following error when performing `vacuum`:

> 'SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error'

I have the following code for vacuum query:

```
_connection.Execute("vacuum");
```

I tried SQLiteCommand and create a command, but it gave me the same error. This code was OK before I update from package version 1.3.3 to 1.7.335.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, see issue https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/958 .You can use the previous version instead.

Comment: @Vincent hmm yeah I think it is a bug, the issue description it is like my problem. Then I think I will stay with the current version until I will port to .NetCore and WPF

Answer (score 1):

using `System.Data.SQLite`, vacuum only works, after deleting the tables.

I was not able to initialize my dataBase file using the corrects arguments to create a file with 'automatic vacuum'. This is the best way to deal with this situation.

```cs
using System.Data.SQLite;
...

cmd.CommandText = $"DROP TABLE MyTable;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = $"vacuum;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is not a best approach, but works well to my purposes.